# Showing two distinct subspaces have different annihilators

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem which states:

Show that different closed subspaces $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ of a normed space $X$ have different annihilators.

Here the annihilators of a set is the set of functionals $f\in X'$ such that the functional is 0 everywhere on the given set.

Here's my attempt so far:

Since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are different subspaces there exists a $y_1\in Y_1$ with $y_1 \notin Y_2$. Furthermore, one can construct a functional $f$ such that $f(y_1)\neq 0$. Now one can make use of the Hahn-Banach theorem to make an extension of that given functional $f$. This is where I get stuck. I have a question regarding this.

Question: The problem I'm having with the Hahn-Banach theorem is in terms of how I can extend the functional $f$. It would make sense to be able to extend the functional to be $0$ for all $y_2\in Y_2$ since then one can see that $f$ belongs to the annihilators for $Y_2$ but not $Y_1$ since $f(y_1)\neq 0$. My question is then how I could argue for this. Do I have a free choice as to how I extend my functional on $X$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q : X\to X/Y_2$ be the quotient map $x\mapsto x+Y_2$. Then $Q(y)=0$ for $y\in Y_2$ and $Q(y_1)\neq 0$. Now, by Hahn-Banach we find a functional $\ell\in (X/Y_2)'$ such that $\ell(Q(y_1))\neq 0$. Then $f = \ell\circ Q\in X'$, $f(y) = 0$ for all $y\in Y_2$, and $f(y_1)\neq 0$.